# deleting items from the back of a deque

Tags: python, deque

I'm using a dequeue in Python. I know that for deleting a certain item from a dequeue I can do it by its index. like this:

```
from collections import deque
deq = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
del deq[1]
```

Now I want to delete multiple items from the end of the dequeue, so I use this:

```
from collections import deque

deq = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
for i in range(1, 5):
    del deq[-i]
print(deq)
```

I expect the new `deq` to be `deq=[1, 2, 3, 4]` but the output is `deq = [1, 3, 5, 7]`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the last element has index `-1`. When you delete the last element, the next element to delete still has index `-1`

```
from collections import deque

deq = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
for i in range(1, 5):
    del deq[-1]
```

Maybe a nicer alternative is

```
deq.pop()
```

which pops the last element (and returns it)

Comment: Thank you. For deleting multiple items from a deque is there a similar approach to list (I mean for example `del mlist[-4:]`) or the only way is to use a for loop like the one you have mentioned in your post?

Comment: there's no notion of slice in deque, probably because elements aren't consecutive in memory. So a loop is your best friend ATM. or convert to list, slice, convert back to deque (no loop but underperformant...)

Comment: I wanted to improve the speed and performance, so if converting to list and ... leads to poor performance, it's better to use a for loop.

Comment: you're using deque for a reason: fast insertion/rotation. Else don't use that :)